# Orthonormal Basis - Angle of Rotation with respect to Standard Orthonormal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, orthogonality, change-of-basis

I have an orthonormal basis ${\bf{b}}_1$ and ${\bf{b}}_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to find out the angle of rotation. I added a little picture here. I essentially want to find $\theta$

[image]

I know that I can compute the angle between two vectors but then there are $4$ combinations here

- $\theta_{11} = \arccos({\bf{b}}_1^\top{\bf{e}}_1)$
- $\theta_{12} = \arccos({\bf{b}}_1^\top{\bf{e}}_2)$
- $\theta_{21} = \arccos({\bf{b}}_2^\top{\bf{e}}_1)$
- $\theta_{22} = \arccos({\bf{b}}_2^\top{\bf{e}}_2)$

How would one know which angle is correct? Importantly, here I used the labels $b_1$, $b_2$ in the same order as $e_1$ and $e_2$ but that's not necessarily the same order geometically!

Comment: The essence of your question is how to determine which of $\textbf{b}_i$ is the rotated x axis and which is the rotated y axis.  A simple test for this is to take a cross product: If $\textbf{b}_1\times\textbf{b}_2 = \textbf{e}_1\times \textbf{e}_2$, then $\textbf{b}_1$ is the rotated x, and you can find the angle from $\arccos(\textbf{b}_1^T \textbf{e}_1)=\arccos(\textbf{b}_2^T \textbf{e}_2)$.   Otherwise swap the indices on $\textbf{b}_i$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just compute all of the $\theta_{ij}$ and take the one that appears twice.  Explicitly, $\theta_{11}=\theta$, $\theta_{12}=\theta-\pi/2$, $\theta_{21}=\theta+\pi/2$, and $\theta_{22}=\theta$ ($\mod 2\pi$ at least), so the angle you want is the only one that appears twice in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{b}_1 = (x_1, y_1)$.  Then, $\theta = \operatorname{atan2}(y_1, x_1)$.

$\operatorname{atan2}(y_1, x_1)$ is the two-argument form of arcus tangent, equivalent to $\arctan(y_1 / x_1)$ except that the two-argument form takes the quadrant (signs of both $x_1$ and $y_1$) into account.

---

If you do not know which of $\mathbf{b}_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $\mathbf{b}_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ to use, then
$$\begin{aligned}
d &= x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 \\
\theta &= \begin{cases}
\operatorname{atan2}(y_1, x_1), & d \ge 0 \\
\operatorname{atan2}(y_2, x_2), & d \lt 0 \\
\end{cases} \end{aligned}$$
Here, $d \gt 0$ if $\mathbf{b}_2$ is counterclockwise from $\mathbf{b}_1$, and $d \lt 0$ if clockwise.  This uses the vector which is the clockwise one of the pair.

---

Note that for arbitrary coordinate system $\mathbf{e}_1$, $\mathbf{e}_2$, you can use
$$\begin{aligned}
x_1 &= \mathbf{b}_1^T \mathbf{e}_1 \\
y_1 &= \mathbf{b}_1^T \mathbf{e}_2 \\
x_2 &= \mathbf{b}_2^T \mathbf{e}_1 \\
y_2 &= \mathbf{b}_2^T \mathbf{e}_2 \\
\end{aligned}$$
above.

Comment: How did you come up with this and do you have some resource I could use?

Comment: @Physics_Student: By definition, we have$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned} x &= r \cos \theta \\ y &= r \sin\theta \end{aligned} \right. \quad \iff \quad \left\lbrace \begin{aligned} r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\ \theta &= \operatorname{atan2}(y, x) \end{aligned} \right.$$The $d$ term is the 2D analog of vector cross product, and its sign reflects the clockwise/counterclockwise order of the two vectors via $$\sin\theta = \frac{x_1 y_2 - y_1 x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}}$$where $\theta$ is positive if measured counterclockwise.  Sorry, I don't have any links on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using the complex plane in this situation. Each
point in the $\,x\,y\,$ plane is associated with a complex number. Thus,
$\,\mathbf{e}_1 \equiv 1\,$ and $\,\mathbf{e}_2 \equiv i.\,$ Similarly, for any two orthogonal **unit** basis vectors $\,\mathbf{b}_1 \equiv z_1\,$ and
$\,\mathbf{b}_2 \equiv z_2\,$ where $\,z_2 = z_1 i.\,$ More precisely, if
$\,\mathbf{b}_1 := (x_1,y_1),\,$ then $\,\mathbf{b}_2 := (x_2,y_2) = (-y_1,x_1).$
You may need to reverse the roles of $\,\mathbf{b}_1\,$ and $\,\mathbf{b}_2\,$ to
ensure this.

Because $\,\mathbf{b}_1\,$ is a unit vector, we get $\,z_1 = e^{i\theta}\,$
for some angle $\,\theta.$ Compute this angle using
$\,\theta = \text{atan2}(y,x)\,$ where
[atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) is the "2-argument arctangent". If $\,\text{atan2}\,$ is not available, use the
identity
$$\text{atan2}(y,x) = 
2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

You have drawn the angle $\theta$ as an arc from ${\bf e}_1$ to ${\bf b}_1,$
so apparently you already know intuitively that this is the angle you want,
implying that you want you use the angle
$\theta_{11} = \arccos( {\bf b}_1^\top {\bf e}_1).$
But this is only half the story.

You are rotating both basis vectors in the same direction in the same plane, so you will always find that

$$
\cos(\theta_{11}) = {\bf b}_1^\top {\bf e}_1 = {\bf b}_2^\top {\bf e}_2 = \cos(\theta_{22}).
$$

Choose either one, it's the same either way.

Another way to see this is to observe from the figure that the pair of vectors $({\bf e}_2, {\bf b}_2)$ is just the
pair of vectors $({\bf e}_1, {\bf b}_1)$
rotated by a right angle counterclockwise.
The angle between each pair of vectors is the same.

Now for the other half of the story:

When you take the arc cosine, you get an angle $\theta$ in the range
$0 \leq \theta \leq \pi,$
indicating that you can rotate ${\bf e}_1$ and ${\bf e}_2$
to ${\bf b}_1$ and ${\bf b}_2$ by rotating them through $\theta$ radians
in either the counterclockwise or clockwise direction.
But this result does not tell you whether the rotation is clockwise or counterclockwise.

By convention, we usually want $\theta$ to be positive for a counterclockwise rotation, negative for a clockwise rotation.

Assuming the vectors ${\bf e}_1$ and ${\bf e}_2$ are arranged in the usual counterclockwise orientation as shown in your figure,
a counterclockwise rotation more than $0$ but less than $\pi$ radians will put
${\bf b}_1$ on the same side of ${\bf e}_1$ as ${\bf e}_2$,
so ${\bf b}_2^\top {\bf e}_1$ will be positive.
With a clockwise rotation, ${\bf b}_2^\top {\bf e}_1$ will be negative.
So a rule to decide the direction of rotation is:

- Counterclockwise if ${\bf b}_2^\top {\bf e}_1 > 0$,
  so let $\theta = \arccos({\bf b}_1^\top {\bf e}_1).$
- Clockwise if ${\bf b}_2^\top {\bf e}_1 < 0$,
  so let $\theta = -\arccos({\bf b}_1^\top {\bf e}_1).$

If ${\bf b}_2^\top {\bf e}_1 = 0$ then either direction of rotation has the same result, so you can choose arbitrarily.

Note that in general you will find that
${\bf b}_2^\top {\bf e}_1 = - {\bf b}_1^\top {\bf e}_2.$

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to construct orthogonal matrix with column vectors $B=[b_1 \ \ b_2 \ \ b_1 \times b_2]$.
(I assume here that $b_1$ and $b_2$ are normalized to unit length)
and to use trace of such matrix $\text{tr}(B)$.

Then we have immediately  $\text{tr}(B)=1+2\cos(\theta)$.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Determining_the_angle

Comment: Note that the presented method is useful not only for a rotation about $z$ axis (in this case you have simply $b_1 \times b_2=[ 0 \ \ 0 \ \ 1]^T$), but about any axis in 3D.